# Using SAP .NET Connector 3.0, slow login?

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector

The question is basically a "am I don't something wrong?" or "It just is that way".

I am logging into my SAP system using the following code. Configuration file is configured for SNC

```
Backend = new BackendConfig();
RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(Backend);
SapRfcDestination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("P38");

SapRap = SapRfcDestination.Repository;

// Create the function for MD04
BapiMD04 = SapRap.CreateFunction("MD_STOCK_REQUIREMENTS_LIST_API");
```

To complete all the above takes around 30 seconds.

Logging into SAP the normal way using SAP and the Login Pad takes 4 seconds.

Will using the SAP connector always be that slow or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT 1:
BackendConfig class

```
public class BackendConfig : IDestinationConfiguration
{
    public RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(String destinationName)
    {
        if ("P38".Equals(destinationName))
        {
            RfcConfigParameters parms = new RfcConfigParameters();
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, "SAPP38.Danfoss.net");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, "86");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SncMode, "1");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SncPartnerName, "p:SAPServiceP38@danfoss.net");
            // parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User, "AUTO0101");
            // parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, "anyth1ng");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, "010");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, "EN");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, "5");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.MaxPoolSize, "10");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.IdleTimeout, "600");
            return parms;
        }

        else if ("T38".Equals(destinationName))
        {
            RfcConfigParameters parms = new RfcConfigParameters();
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, "blahblahblah");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, "81");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SncMode, "1");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SncPartnerName, "blahblahblah");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, "010");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, "EN");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, "5");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.MaxPoolSize, "10");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.IdleTimeout, "600");
            return parms;
        }
        else return null;
    }
    // The following two are not used in this example:
    public bool ChangeEventsSupported()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public event RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler ConfigurationChanged;
}
```

Comment: .Net Connector should take less than a second to log in. Could your "BackendConfig" be the problem?

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek just added the code for the BackendConfig, anything you see that can cause the slowdown?

Comment: no, seems simple enough. But you are connecting using a secure network connection. Can you try to just log on using username and password? Maybe the delay occurs in the SAP system itself. You could start the SAP system trace in the system you are connecting to and see what happens there.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine.

In my experience of the SAP Connector, the initial connection is *always* slow - more so than just logging in through the SAP client. Subsequent calls to the connector are much faster as the connection has been established.

30 seconds does seem a bit much though. Check:

- There's no DNS lookup issues for the server you're specifying
- You have the latest version of the SAP Connector from the SAP Service
  Marketplace

Comment: Cheers for the reply, I will check out the DNS.

Comment: If it's the CreateFunction line that's taking the time, it's likely to be the amount of metadata it's downloading, which I believe is subsequently cached. Put breakpoint in after that and check the volume of metadata present in the MD_STOCK_REQUIREMENTS_LIST_API (BapiMD04) object

Comment: Just timed it, takes about 21 seconds to get to the Create function line. So its about 20 seconds to login

Comment: Welcome to the world of SAP >:|

Comment: Yay!!! lol. Its just annoying when colleagues are asking me why does my program take so long to login when they can get into SAP almost right away.

Comment: I agree with Gareth. You don't need a router string? Have you tried to pass the IP-Address as Application-Server and not the FQDN? Can you please check if the assign of "SapRfcDestination.Repository" is taking so long?